# grub refuses to install to raid array

Tags: ubuntu, raid, grub, bootloader

I have a software raid 0 setup with dual booting Windows 7 and Ubuntu 12.04. The GRUB bootloader that is already on the hard drive seems to work fine. However, since the latest package update for grub, it refuses to install the new version to the hard disk. grub-install throws the following error:

```
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: error: cannot find a GRUB drive for /dev/mapper/< raid name>_RAID0p9. Check your device.map.
Auto-detection of a filesystem of /dev/mapper/< raid name>_RAID0p9 failed.
Try with --recheck.
If the problem persists please report this together with the output of "/usr/sbin/grub-probe --device-map="/boot/grub/device.map" --target=fs -v /boot/grub" to < bug-grub@gnu.org>
```

update-grub pops the same

```
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: error: cannot find a GRUB drive for /dev/mapper/< raid name>_RAID0p9. Check your device.map.
```

every alternate line.

I don't understand what exactly is going on. I'm afraid to reinstall the grub package because it might mess up the boot, which currently works fine. Is it safe to just ignore this?

**Edit:** the system is an Alienware M17xR4, I don't know how to better describe the motherboard.

**Edit 2:** This is the output of "ls -alFR /dev/mapper/":

```
/dev/mapper/:
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root     260 Sep 19  2012 ./
drwxr-xr-x 16 root root    4500 Sep 19 09:03 ../
crw-------  1 root root 10, 236 Sep 19 09:03 control
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       7 Sep 19 09:03 isw_ccdceegjed_M17x_RAID0 -> ../dm-0
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       7 Sep 19 09:03 isw_ccdceegjed_M17x_RAID0p1 -> ../dm-1
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       7 Sep 19 09:03 isw_ccdceegjed_M17x_RAID0p2 -> ../dm-2
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       7 Sep 19 09:03 isw_ccdceegjed_M17x_RAID0p3 -> ../dm-3
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       7 Sep 19 09:03 isw_ccdceegjed_M17x_RAID0p4 -> ../dm-4
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       7 Sep 19 09:03 isw_ccdceegjed_M17x_RAID0p5 -> ../dm-5
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       7 Sep 19 09:03 isw_ccdceegjed_M17x_RAID0p6 -> ../dm-6
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       7 Sep 19 09:03 isw_ccdceegjed_M17x_RAID0p7 -> ../dm-7
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       7 Sep 19 09:03 isw_ccdceegjed_M17x_RAID0p8 -> ../dm-8
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       7 Sep 19 09:03 isw_ccdceegjed_M17x_RAID0p9 -> ../dm-9
```

By default, /boot/grub/device.map does not exist. This is its contents after creating it via "/usr/sbin/grub-mkdevicemap":

```
(hd0)   /dev/disk/by-id/ata-ST9500423AS_6WS2GYX3
(hd1)   /dev/disk/by-id/ata-ST9500423AS_S2V01385
(hd2)   /dev/mapper/isw_ccdceegjed_M17x_RAID0
```

Comment: By "software RAID" do you really mean "firmware RAID", as created through your motherboard?  If so, we need to know your motherboard model.

Comment: @Charles Yes, added motherboard info. The RAID is created through the bios

Comment: Okay, that'll be based on Intel's H77 chipset.  Can you edit in the output of `ls -alFR /dev/mapper` and the contents of the `device.map` file (should be in `/boot/grub`)?